# Why is my async function running synchronously Python3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to run a function on separate threads using `asyncio` and `futures`. I have a decorator which takes the long running function and its argument asynchronously and outputs its value. Unfortunately the processes seem to not be working asynchronously.

```
def multiprocess(self, function, executor=None, *args, **kwargs):
    async def run_task(function, *args, **kwargs):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        async def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                execution_runner = executor or self._DEFAULT_POOL_
                executed_job = execution_runner.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
                print(
                    f"Pending {function.__name__}:",
                    execution_runner._work_queue.qsize(),
                    "jobs",
                )
                print(
                    f"Threads: {function.__name__}:", len(execution_runner._threads)
                )
                future = await asyncio.wrap_future(executed_job)
                return future

        return wrap

    return asyncio.run(run_task(function, *args, **kwargs))
```

To call the decorator I have two functions `_async_task` and `task_function`. `_async_task` contains a loop that runs `task_function` for each document that needs to be processed.

```
@staticmethod
def _async_task(documents):
    processed_docs = asyncio.run(task_function(documents))
    return processed_docs
```

`task_function` processes each document in documents as below,

```
@multiprocess
async def task_function(documents):
    processed_documents = None
    try:
        for doc in documents:
            processed_documents = process_document(doc)
            print(processed_documents)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    return processed_documents
```

The clue that this doesn't work asynchronously is that the diagnostics I have for the multithreading decorator print the following.

```
Pending summarise_news: 0 jobs
Threads: summarise_news: 2
```

Since there's no pending jobs and the entire process takes as long as the synchronous run, it's running synchronously.

Comment: What, specifically, do you expect to run asynchronously here? `_async_task` just calls `task_function` once. `task_function` does run in a worker pool thread. But you are using `asyncio.run` in `_async_task`, which means it will block until `task_function` completes. Any subsequent `_async_task` calls will not run until the previous one finishes.

Comment: @dano looking at the answer below. It seems like I've misunderstood how async works in python. Essentially I'd `task_function` to work asynchronously and gather all async'd run outputs into data structure so a downstream sync function can process it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some issues setting up your code, but I think I've come up with an answer.

First of all, as @dano mentioned in his comment, `asyncio.run` blocks until the coroutine running is completed. Thus, you won't get any speedup from using this approach.

I used a slightly modified `multiprocess` decorator

```py
def multiprocess(executor=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def run_task(function, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):

            execution_runner = executor or DEFAULT_EXECUTOR
            executed_job = execution_runner.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
            print(
                f"Pending {function.__name__}:",
                execution_runner._work_queue.qsize(),
                "jobs",
            )
            print(
                f"Threads: {function.__name__}:", len(execution_runner._threads)
            )
            future = asyncio.wrap_future(executed_job)

            return future

        return wrap
    return run_task
```

As you can see, there's no `asyncio.run` here, and both the decorator and inner wrapper are synchronous since `asyncio.wrap_future` does not need `await`.

The updated `multiprocess` decorator is now used with `process_document` function. The reason for that is you won't get any benefit of parallelizing a function that calls blocking functions in a sequence. You have **to convert your blocking function** to be runnable in an executor instead.

**NOTE** that this dummy `process_document` is exactly like I described - fully blocking and synchronous.

```py
@multiprocess()
def process_document(doc):
    print(f"Processing doc: {doc}...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"Doc {doc} done.")
```

Now, to the last point. We already made `process_document` kind of asynchronous by converting it to be runnable in an executor, BUT it still matters HOW exactly you invoke it.

Consider the following examples:

```py
for doc in documents:
    result = await process_document(doc)
```

```py
results = await asyncio.gather(*[process_document(doc) for doc in documents])
```

In the former one, we will wait for coroutines sequentially, having to wait until one finishes before starting another.
In the latter example, they will be executed in parallel, so it **really depends on how exactly** you invoke your coroutine execution.

Here's the full code snipped I used:

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time


DEFAULT_EXECUTOR = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)


def multiprocess(executor=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def run_task(function, *args, **kwargs):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):

            execution_runner = executor or DEFAULT_EXECUTOR
            executed_job = execution_runner.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
            print(
                f"Pending {function.__name__}:",
                execution_runner._work_queue.qsize(),
                "jobs",
            )
            print(
                f"Threads: {function.__name__}:", len(execution_runner._threads)
            )
            future = asyncio.wrap_future(executed_job)

            return future

        return wrap
    return run_task


@multiprocess()
def process_document(doc):
    print(f"Processing doc: {doc}...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"Doc {doc} done.")


async def task_function_sequential(documents):
    start = time.time()
    for doc in documents:
        await process_document(doc)

    end = time.time()
    print(f"task_function_sequential took: {end-start}s")


async def task_function_parallel(documents):
    start = time.time()

    jobs = [process_document(doc) for doc in documents]
    await asyncio.gather(*jobs)

    end = time.time()
    print(f"task_function_parallel took: {end-start}s")


async def main():
    documents = [i for i in range(5)]
    await task_function_sequential(documents)
    await task_function_parallel(documents)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Notice that the `task_function_parallel` example still takes around 4 seconds, instead of 2, because the thread pool is limited to 4 workers, and the number of jobs is 5, so the last job will be waiting for some workers to be available.

Comment: Really appreciate all the detail. This has helped me alot in understanding async behaviour in python3.7+